# How can I create a custom iterator for the Active Record design pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, activerecord, iterator

I am trying to implement a custom iterator for the Active Records pattern but no matter what I do I can't get it to work correctly in a foreach loop.

My goal is to improve performance when processing numerous records from my database. I intend to have the iterator hold a set amount of records and automatically get the next batch of records if there are more in the result set.

The problem is that even when processing only 100 or so records with the iterator the forrach loop generates an infinite loop and thus a memory overflow.

My database uses PDO but that shouldn't be a problem.

Here is the code for the custom RecordIterator class:

```
<?php
// If it's going to need the database, then it's 
// probably smart to require it before we start.
require_once('database.php');
class RecordIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $total = 0;
    public $resultSet;
    public $recordTable;
    public $recordClass;
    private $remainingRecords = 0;
    private $records = array(); 
    private $hasMore = true;
    public const MAX_RECORDS = 100;
    public function initialize(){
        global $database;
        $this->remainingRecords = $database->numRows($this->resultSet);
        $this->total = $this->remainingRecords;
            $this->refill();
    }
    private function refill(){
        global $database;
        $i=1;
        $this->records=array();
        while (($row = $database->fetchArray($this->resultSet)) && ($i<self::MAX_RECORDS)){
            $this->records[] = $this->recordClass::initFromRecord($row);
            $this->remainingRecords--;
            $i++;
        }
        $this->rewind();
        if($this->remainingRecords<1){
            $this->hasMore = false;
        }
    }
    public function __construct() {
        $this->rewind();
    }
    public function rewind() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }
    public function current() {
        return $this->records[$this->position];
    }
    public function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }
    public function next() {
        if($this->hasNextRecord()){
            ++$this->position;
        }elseif($this->hasMore == true){
            $this->refill();
        }else{
        }
    }
    public function hasNextRecord(){
        $nextRecord = $this->records[$this->position+1];
        $posOffset = self::MAX_RECORDS - $this->position;
        if(($posOffset>1) && !empty($nextRecord)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
}
    public function valid() {
        return !(empty($this->records[$this->position]));
    }
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->resultSet->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Globals in a class destroys the encapsulation of the class

Comment: Good catch. I will have to figure out how to resolve it.